# Router suddently stop working, new router doesn't work either

Tags: windows, router

So I live in a student dorm and I have an Internet connection provided by the University. We are supposed to have an ethernet cable plugged into a socket on the wall, the Cable connection is called Eduroam, and I gave the Student Dorms administration my credentials that I use to log-in Eduroam, so that it is my account and my personal connection that is reaching me.

They have a stupid policy here which forbids us from having a router (we pay the internet bill in separate, and they are afraid that people share internet and split the bill...), but I own a tablet and a smart phone, and I like to have a little mobility with my laptop as well, so I went ahead and bought an Asus RT-N12 router one year ago, plugged it in (don't remember if I configured it or just ran some sort of wizard), and I used it just fine... until a couple of weeks ago. I was browsing the internet when suddenly the connection gets extremely slow, so I turn the router off and on, it didn't work - I couldn't even get Wi-Fi internet anymore. I ended up trying a whole range of things (reseting it, changing the SSID/password, firmware upgrade) nothing seemed to work...

The crazy party is this: if I plugged my pc with the LAN cable to the wall, I'd have connection no problems... If I plugged the PC only to the router, and the router ONLY to the power, I would be able to access the router's configuration page either by Wireless or by cable... In the configuration page there is a wizard that tries to set up a connection, which at some point asks you to turn the modem off and on... since I don't have a modem, I just plugged in the ethernet cable from the wall to the router, and whenever I did this the router would JUST freeze and the configuration page or anything else would be accessible.

After hours of rage and failed attempts, I decided that it should be the router's problem, so I sent it back for guarantee. I got a new one in no time, and was very happy that my problem was almost solved, when I get home and try it... Out of the box, same thing happens:

- plugged the router to the power and turned it on,
- connected it only to the PC, accessed the config page
- started to run  the automatic internet configuration
- at the point the wizard tells me to plug the router to the LAN in the wall, the thing freezes and I can't do anything else.

After this, I tried to manually configure it (I tried to clone the PC MAC address, it didn't work), but it was kinda hard since I don't really know what "type" of internet connection do I have. Now I have a brand new router that I can't use, and I am anchored with my laptop to a LAN socket. 
My questions is: could the Internet provider in the uni have decided this year to block the use of Routers? If so, wouldn't MAC cloning solve it? Or could it be, against all odds, that the second router is broken too?

Anyways, I ran ipconfig/all in command while having this problem and here is what I got (since I am kind of a newbie to this stuff, I'd appreciate the kindness, if you think I am publishing stuff that I shouldn't be showing publicly, and tell me about it, thank you!)

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Me>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : RMCN
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : stw-wh.uni-jena.de

Wireless LAN adapter Ligação de Área Local* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1A-EE-65-5C-6A-55
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : stw-wh.uni-jena.de
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-C3-7B-20-D5-AE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::19b:e2c4:dcc3:a904%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.42.16.87(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 4 de novembro de 2014 17:08:03
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 2 de dezembro de 2014 17:08:02
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.42.16.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 141.35.0.13 (sometimes ends with .12)
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 152093563
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E4-67-D2-10-C3-7B-20-D5-AE

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 141.35.1.16
                                       141.35.1.80
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-EE-65-5C-6A-55
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd77:48a2:3c2a:832f%3(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.9(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 4 de novembro de 2014 17:07:53
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 5 de novembro de 2014 17:07:51
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 62451301
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E4-67-D2-10-C3-7B-20-D5-AE

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{892CDAFE-A3D0-458C-B411-E84388D24E65}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Placa Microsoft ISATAP #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.stw-wh.uni-jena.de:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : stw-wh.uni-jena.de
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Placa Microsoft ISATAP #15
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5efe:10.42.16.87%11(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 285212672
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-E4-67-D2-10-C3-7B-20-D5-AE

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 141.35.1.16
                                       141.35.1.80
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: What happens if you move off campus and then try to use the router? Maybe a better option...

Comment: I haven't tried that because I am living abroad and pretty much everyone I know lives in a dorm, but I will try that as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously they are able to detect and ban your router.

Comment: Hey Loren. Is this possible even with two different routers? I thought you could only ban MAC addresses, or can you apply network policies to any router?